# How to see the assembly code of a Python file?

Tags: python, disassembly

Out of curiosity I would like to see the assembly instructions that correspond to the code of a .py file. Are there any trustworthy solutions you can propose?

Comment: Are you talking about Python bytecode or the host CPU?

Comment: @Andrew About the host CPU!

Comment: I'm not sure you understand how things work here. Python is compiled to bytecode which is executed by the Python VM. It may or may not be JITted to native machine code.

Comment: Define *trustworthy*; you mean you fear there are methods that'll lie to you about the instructions presented?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The [`dis` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) disassembles code objects (extracting those from functions, classes and objects with a `__dict__` namespace).

This means you can use it to disassemble whole modules:

```
import dis

dis.dis(dis)
```

although this isn't nearly as interesting as you may think as most modules contain several functions and classes, leading to a lot of output.

I usually focus on smaller functions with specific aspects I am interested in; like what bytecode is generated for a chained comparison:

```
def f(x):
    return 1 < x ** 2 < 100

dis.dis(f)
```

for example.

Comment: Not sure why you're getting downvoted, the OP didn't specify what he even wanted, and I think this answer is great.

Comment: It could be there are people that feel the question is of such bad quality I should not have dared to answer. I'd wish they'd speak out so we can discuss wether or not the question is at all salvageable.

Comment: original post asked for assembly code, but dis module shows byte code.

Comment: @penguin that is what the asker meant by assembly code. The Python evaluation loop, coded in C, is driven entirely by bytecode.