# Machine code representation of my python program

Tags: python, assembly, machine-code

I want to see the machine level (assembly) instructions associated with my generic python program. Is there a simple way of  finding (looking at) the assembly instructions generated by my program.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Machine code != assembly != bytecode. Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/28776723/11301900.

Comment: for an intro to generating bytecode, this is a good resource: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generate-byte-code-file-python/

Comment: CPython never JIT compiles your Python to native machine code; it only interprets.  Are you using Cython or PyPy?

Comment: Machine code and assembly language are logically equivalent, just different ways of representing instructions that a real CPU can run.  Except it can also mean bytecode-assembly (text representation of bytecode instead of machine code). Your question is now unclear whether you want asm for native code (which doesn't exist in CPython) or asm for bytecode.

Comment: I would be asking for byte code representation. Perhaps this question would be better suited for a language like C.

Comment: It looks like Pypy speeds up python by JIT compilation to assembly. Is there a way of seeing the associated assembly program to your PyPy program?

Comment: Well what do you *really* want to know?  More detail about how CPython interprets?  Or what an efficient hand-written asm version of your program would look like in native asm?  Translating by hand to C and then using a C compiler ([How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](//stackoverflow.com/q/38552116)) would give you something like that.  But Python is a dynamic language with arbitrary-precision integers so it's not simple.

Comment: As for PyPy, I don't know much about it.  You could certainly attach a debugger to a running process and interrupt, and you'll probably be in JITed code.  (If your program spends most of its time in JITed code (likely for a long-running loop), not the interpreter or JIT compiler or other parts of PyPy's own code, then stopping with control-C inside GDB a few times will likely put you inside JITed code at least once.